# How can I prevent scroll from decreasing the width of the block?

Tags: html, css

I have a small script that adds blocks with the text of the block class and the container container, but when there are a lot of blocks, a scroll bar appears and reduces the width of the blocks - how can I avoid such a shift in width

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/3.1.4/vue.global.prod.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="app" class="container">
    <div v-for="i in messages" :key="i" class="block">
      {{ i }}
    </div>
  </div>


</body>
<script>
  Vue.createApp({
    data: () => ({
      messages: [],
    }),

    mounted() {
      setInterval(
        function () {
          this.messages.push(Math.random().toString(32).slice(2));
        }.bind(this)
        , 100)
    },
  }).mount('#app');

</script>
<style>
  .container {
    background: yellow;
    height: 50vh;
    width: 5vw;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;

    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
  }

  .container::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 5vmin;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: black;
  }

  .container::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: red;
  }

  .block {
    background: green;
    width: 5vw;

  }
</style>

</html>
```

The width of the block can be reduced - for example, it is noticeable by the displacement of the centered text when the scroll appears.
Can I make a scroll like position: absolute ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: You can not. There is no native way to disable scroll from consuming space.

Long answer and workaround: just add one more wrapper with `overflow: hidden`, make the inner container 17px bigger than the wrapper (17px is default scrollbar width on Chrome, Windows. you can use for example 20px if you want to), set item width to be equal to the width of the wrapper, so when inner grow - scroll will appear but will be hidden.

Keep in mind that it's a bad solution, as you are breaking default browser UX, and your user will not understand that block is scrollable. So, it's better to make the previous steps I've described **and** add a virtual scrollbar that will appear at least on hover. You can check how it works in popular fake scrollbar plugins, for example [this one](https://kingsora.github.io/OverlayScrollbars/#!demos/basic). Also you can just use one of those plugins in your application